# WordPress: list intersection of two categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-list-categories

I hope someone can point me in the right direction here as I've been hitting a dead end on my searches.

I'm developing a WordPress theme for a friend who has both recipes and travel stories on her site. The development site is currently here;
http://www.culinaryanthropologist2.plumb-design.com/recipes/

At the moment I'm using `wp_list_categories` in the sidebar to list the countries for the recipes but this also shows countries that also contain travel stories. What I'm looking for is a way to list all countries that only have recipes in them.

Can I use `wp_list_categories` to do that or do I need a custom query?

I'm sure it is an easy thing to do but all of the posts I'm finding on the subject appear to be way over my head.

Many thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: So recipes and travel stories are custom post types? If so, try this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-categories-for-custom-post-type

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No they are just regular post categories.

Comment: So what are the countries then – sub-categories, or what? Please describe what model is used to structure the content in more detail.

Comment: At the moment the site has several categories; recipes, travel, countries (of which there are countries listed as children) etc. Each post is labeled with one or more categories so a recipe from Italy will be tagged with recipes and Countries > Italy, a travel story from Spain will be tagged as travel & Countries > Spain. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

when you do post then please add tag on that post. and using this code. i hope it will work.

```
<?php
$orderby = 'countries';
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$taxonomy = 'travel';
$title = '';

$args = array(
  'orderby' => $orderby,
  'show_count' => $show_count,
  'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
  'title_li' => $title
);
?>
<ul>
<?php
wp_list_categories($args);
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This isn't working for me, I suspect because I'm not using custom taxonomies.